# Error while reading a text file at CLion

Tags: c++, file, clion

I'm trying to read a text file. The below code works in Codeblocks but doesn't work in CLion.

If I change "input.txt" in the below to "C:\Users\User\ClionProjects\program\input.txt" the program works at CLion too. How can I make the code work with just "input.txt"?

```
ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("input.txt");
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {


            myReadFile >> output;
            cout<<output;


        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    myReadFile.close();
```

Comment: Find the settting for your project's "working directory" in CLion.

Comment: Check where your binary is being created. Is it in the same directory as input.txt?